# How to receive the keystrokes without having a text field focused?

Tags: java, swing, usb, jtextfield

In my Swing application I am using a bar-code scanner attached to the machine using USB port. I want to trigger an action (popup a window) as soon as some thing is scanned using bar-code scanner. I do not have any text field (e.g. `JTextField`) focused before the scanning is done.

But if I scan something now without any focus on text filed it is scanning and not registering the value to the application, just like how we press `A,B,C,D` in the keyboard without having the cursor focused on a text field region. I need to notify the application internally when the scanning happens and register the value from bar-code scanner in a text field.

How do I do this?

Comment: any input box.. like JTextField

Comment: For `JTextField` use `setText(String)` (as opposed to whatever nonsense is currently implemented). I don't speak for any other components 'like' `JTextField` (unless explicitly identified).

Comment: JFormattedTextField with InputMask

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson: I am not looking for a method to set the text in JTextField. I am looking for some kind of notifier that notifies me when a scanning is done on bar-code scanner. Thanks for the edit by the way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add KeyListener to any component including your window. So if at least something is in focus you will receive the events.

Moreover you can use AWTEventListener: `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(listener, eventMask)`. Play with eventMask to get events you are interesting in. This allows getting event on AWT level. Even if you have 10 separate windows in your application and want to catch events from all of them you can do it in one single place.